# Thread-safely update a singleton's dependency via setter at runtime from scheduled job

Tags: java, spring, singleton, scheduled-tasks, singleton-methods

I have a spring based java app and my goal is to cache a bunch of objects in memory for performance and use a scheduled job to update that cache from the data source periodically.

If I am storing that map in a singleton spring bean, is there a thread safe way to update that map at runtime without making the access / service methods synchronous? Is it possible to do a temporary block of methods that are NOT synchronous on the singleton object while calling `setMap(myNewMap)`? Is it necessary?

```
class MySingletonCache {

  private Map<String, Object> myMap;

  // Called periodically from scheduled job
  public void setMap(Map<String, Object> myMap) {
    this.myMap = myMap;
  }

  // High concurrency, cannot make this synchronous
  public Object findById(String id) {
    return this.myMap.get(id);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement [ReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReadWriteLock.html) for this specific purpose.